# Back button in UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4, uinavigationcontroller

So, I am well aware that when the back button is pressed in classes embedded in `UINavigationControllers`, the previous view's `viewDidAppear()` method is called. However, I need the `viewDidLoad()` method to be called, much like it is with a push `segue` into a scene. Is there a possible way to do this? Maybe by modifying the method that is called when the back button is pressed? What is the method that is called when the back button is pressed? Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just move the code you need called into `viewDidAppear`?

Comment: if I do that, I mess with the order of executed actions and my view loads incorrectly :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly viewWillAppear and then viewDidAppear is getting called on push back. And for lazy loading of views, it is preferable to **add/operate UI subviews in viewWillAppear**, and make them **set view to nil in viewDidDisappear** for memory management.

Comment: Unless you have good reason to, I recommend against unloading your view in viewDidDisappear. A lot of the time this will result in pointless setup/teardown of a view that could have happily remained in memory without causing problems -- I regard your suggestion as a good example of premature optimisation. And thrashing stuff pointlessly is not beneficial for your device's battery life (in theory).

Comment: Thanks Occulus, Definately there are some of the views which are not creating any issue while in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`viewDidLoad` is only called when the view has loaded. There's a difference between views being loaded/unloaded and them appearing/disappearing: a view can disappear without being unloaded. Usually iOS will not unload a view, even if it is hidden/replaced by by another view, unless a low memory situation occurs.

Don't ever call `viewDidLoad` etc. yourself (except for the `super` call in subclass overrides).